# Unable to send/receive custom metadata on Amazon S3 Upload (using ng-file-upload)

Tags: amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

I am using ng-file-upload to upload a JPG file to my S3 Bucket.

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
    url: "https://<my-bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/", 
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        key: "custom-filename.jpg", 
        AWSAccessKeyId: "<AWSAccessKeyId>",
        acl: "public-read", 
        policy: <policy>, 
        signature: <signature>, 
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg", 
        filename: file.name, 
        file: file, 
        Metadata: {
            "x-amz-meta-hello": "Custom Metadata Value"
        }
    }
});
```

I have also tried the following (in the above code)

```
Metadata: {
    hello: "Custom Metadata Value"
}
```

& simply

```
"x-amz-meta-hello": "Custom Metadata Value"
```

I have included the Custom Metadata in my Policy file as

```
["starts-with", "x-amz-meta-hello", ""]
```

Also, the CORS Configuration under Bucket Permissions on S3 is

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-hello</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

The above code and settings are working, the JPG file is successfully uploaded, but somehow the Custom Metadata value is not being set.

On successful upload, I am calling a Lambda function to resize the JPG and storing it in a separate bucket. Even this part is working but I am not able to read the Custom Metadata (x-amz-meta-hello) value in my Lambda Function. I need that value to assign a separate folder to the uploaded file.

To read the Custom Metadata in my Lambda Function

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.headObject({
    Bucket: <BucketName>,
    Key: <S3ObjectKey>
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {   
        console.log(data);
    }     
});
```

Not sure what am I missing here ... Please advise.

Thanks.
(AngularJS version 1.5.0, ng-file-upload version 12.2.9, Google Chrome version 53.0.2785.113 on OSX 10.10.5)

Comment: Strictly from intuition: eliminate the `Metadata: {` and `}` construct, and place the metadata key above the file info:  `... "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",  "x-amz-meta-hello": "Custom Metadata Value",  filename: file.name, ...`

Comment: Thanks ... Worked Perfectly ...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `Metadata: { ... }` construct, because you're building an HTML form, which has a flat keyspace.  Elsewhere you may see metadata given special treatment, where something like `Metadata: { "hello": "world" }` magically becomes `x-amz-meta-hello: world` but that is not applicable, here. Instead, metadata needs to [start with `x-amz-meta-`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata), and since we are [making a `POST` request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html), it is provided in the form data, rather than as a header.

Because the file data needs to be the last form element, place the metadata key above the file info, e.g.:

```
...
"Content-Type": "image/jpeg", 
"x-amz-meta-hello": "Custom Metadata Value", 
filename: file.name, 
...
```

Your [policy condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-PolicyConditions) must reference the metadata name with a `$` in order to work (`["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-hello", ""]`). Note that having the policy is required for the field to be accepted, but this specific condition does not constrain the field to contain a specific value.

Note also that `<ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-hello</ExposeHeader>` is not necessary in order to allow the upload.  `<ExposeHeader>` allows the browser to return that response header to the calling code on an AJAX request. Headers not listed (other than the "simple" standard ones, like `Content-Type`) are otherwise hidden from calling code.  CORS is initially counterintuitive, until you understand that it's based on the idea that the web browser itself is assumed to be well-intentioned but naïve. CORS gives the browser permission to do things that it would not otherwise do, such as returning specific headers back to a caller.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, if you try to add the metadata to the form data object, you get an error response complaining about the extra field. Also from what I understand from the S3 documentation, the metadata is supposed to be provided through headers that start with `x-amz-meta-`. (This allows the file to upload but the metadata does not get set.)

Comment: Nevermind, I was mistaken. For a POST request, the headers are supposed to be sent as form data instead. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

I apologize for the premature downvote.

Comment: Also the policy condition needs to use `$x-amz-meta-hello` in order to work.

Comment: @RahatAhmed thanks, yout edit has been approved, so you can un-downvote at your convenience. :)